# Apple Script Mail Issue Var Type Constant

Tags: ios, email, applescript

I'm trying to create an Apple Script for my Apple Users. To configure their e-mail accounts, they only have to use this Script.

The First part with the imap works great, but in the second part I got an error. In German the error is:

```
"Mail" hat einen Fehler erhalten: password of smtp server "host-cocco.ch"
kann nicht in Typ constant umgewandet werden.
```

The error in english:

```
"Mail" got an error: password of smtp server "host-cocco.ch" 
can not be changed in typ constant.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

```
display dialog "Wie lautet ihre E-Mail-Adresse?" default answer ""
set email to text returned of result
display dialog "Wie lautet ihr Passwort?" default answer ""
set passwort to text returned of result

tell application "Mail"
    set AccountName to email
    set newacct to make new imap account with properties {name:AccountName, user name:email, server name:"host-cocco.ch"}
    tell newacct
        set password to passwort
        set full name to AccountName
        set email addresses to {email}
        set port to 995
        set uses ssl to true
    end tell

    set smtpservername to "host-cocco.ch"
    set smtpusername to email
    set addsmtp to make new smtp server with properties {server name:smtpservername}
    tell addsmtp
        set authentication to password
        set password to passwort
        set uses ssl to true
        set port to 465
        set user name to smtpusername
    end tell
    set newsmtpserver to smtp server (smtpservername & ":" & smtpusername)
    set smtp server of newacct to smtp server newsmtpserver
end tell
```

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
set addsmtp to make new smtp server with properties {server name:smtpservername}
tell addsmtp
    set authentication to password
    set password to passwort
    set uses ssl to true
    set port to 465
    set user name to smtpusername
end tell
```

Is there some logical reason why you are creating the `smtp server` with just a `server name` property and then trying to set its properties afterward? I would suggest that you set *all* these properties in the `with properties` clause.